# When will we have computer programs that can compose mathematical proofs?

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving, automated-reasoning, general-problem-solver

When will it be possible to give a computer program a bunch of assumptions and ask it if a certain statement is true or false, giving a proof or a counterexample respectively?

Answer (score 2):

Arguably we have had this since 1957, with the [General Problem Solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Problem_Solver). However, it is a thorny problem, and like so much in AI, it works fine in toy domains (like the [Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) problem), but fails in real life, as real life is too complex for it to cope.

There is [a list of solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solver) (the category of programs dealing with this issue) on Wikipedia. As of today, it comprises about 40 systems (split into two sub-categories). These work with mathematical equations and presumably also more general problems, assuming they are not too complex.